# Error 404; type Status report ; description Requested resorce unavailable For my struts2 Application

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I am getting 404 error while executing my struts2 application. I ran the application on apache tomcat 8 and I am using eclipse. I appended /Tutorials/getTutorial.action at the end of the url in browser which should tranfer the control to success.jsp, still getting 404 error. My code is
struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation // DTD Struts Configuration 2.0 //EN"
            "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
            <struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/Tutorials">
<action name="getTutorial" class="org.gurjot.javabrains.action">
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
<result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>StartingWithStruts2</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

FirstAction.java

```
package org.gurjot.javabrains.action;
public class FirstAction {
public String execute()
{ System.out.println("hi");
   return "success";


}

}
```

Comment: can you move to `cd $CATALINA_HOME/webapps` and then run `tree` and paste the result here?

Comment: Thanx...can you please tell the location where i have to run the command window and use this command line because i am unfamilliar with this

Comment: `webapps` is a directory relative to tomcat base directory. Tomcat base directory is usually defined as an environment variable `$CATALINA_HOME`

Comment: Do you want my project's directory structure?

Comment: We need to look at the tomcat deployment directory structure to see if it matches your web.xml configuration.

Comment: I have done as you said but cant paste the entire tree here as it is too long . is there some other way of sending?

Comment: try to limit the depth of the command. eg for unix: `tree -L 2`

Comment: can i send d snaps of my tree output to you on mail.. if there's no objection

Comment: You could paste to http://pastebin.com/

Comment: done and the name of file is gurjot_webapp_tree

Comment: You didn't extend ActionSupport :) Try `public class FirstAction extends ActionSupport`

Comment: drop this tutorial, and recreate the project from maven

Comment: can you please send some helpful links for maven ..?

Answer (score 0):

In struts.xml, try adding the Class name

```
<action name="getTutorial" class="org.gurjot.javabrains.action.FirstAction">
<result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
<result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
```

Comment: can you plz specify how i have to do this.

Comment: I have already updated the code here. In the action mapping , mention the class name in the path along with the package

Comment: done as u said but Still its not working

Comment: Can u please share a snapshot of your setup?

Comment: Tomcat directory snaps?

Comment: yes and the worksapce setup

Comment: you have to give me your mail id